# Object passed as prop in vue arrives as string

Tags: javascript, string, object, vue.js, vue-component

https://jsfiddle.net/2xwo87bs/
For Vue to process the object prop I pass to the component, I'll have to convert the string to an object first (in the snippet I've took the easy way out and used `JSON.parse()` ). Is there a way I can pass a real javascript object as a prop directly to the component, without it being interpreted as a string? Note I'll use the component multiple times, which makes an individual `data()` object to pass into the prop, which is then used in the component for the `v-bind`, for each use impractical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a prop like this:

```
<component ok='{"data-x":1}'></component>
```

...you are actually passing the string `'{"data-x":1}'` as the prop value.

You need to use binding to evaluate the prop value:

```
<component v-bind:ok='{"data-x":1}'></component>
```

...or use the shorthand version:

```
<component :ok='{"data-x":1}'></component>
```

This way, it's the object `{"data-x":1}` that gets passed as the prop value.

Comment: How could I have not thought about that. I feel dumb now ;)

Comment: We've all been there :)